# Generic classes with shared static fields in C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-3.5, static

I have a generic class definition similar to this:

```
public sealed class MyClass<TProperty,TOwner>
{
    ...
}
```

Now I'd like any instances of `MyClass<TProperty,TOwner>` regardless of the types of TProperty or TOwner to share a Hashtable. I thought of creating an internal MyClassBase with a protected internal static field of type Hashtable and inherit from that. I really only want the definition of MyClass to have access to this hashtable.

Is this a sound approach? I can't seal MyClassBase, so this probably could lead to opening a can of worms later on...

Are there other approaches for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The protected static Hashtable is a fine approach (make sure you synchronize it). You can't have an internal base class whose derived classes are public - but you can prevent it from being derived outside your assembly by making its default constructor internal:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    internal MyBaseClass() { }

    private static Hashtable _hashtable;

    protected static Hashtable Hashtable
    {
        get
        {
            if(_hashtable == null)
            {
                _hashtable = Hashtable.Synchronized(new Hashtable());
            }
            return _hashtable;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oi, yeah, not enough sleep, an internal class is obviously less accessible than a public class.

I have synchronized locks... Thanks for the internal constructor tip...

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to make an `internal static class` with an exposed member, and only access it from `MyClass<T,U>`. Sure, it'd be visible within your assembly, but that's easily controlled compared to a `protected` member. Just make sure to only use it in your `MyClass<T,U>` and it'll be fine.